# Verify that $\sqrt{2}|z| \geq | R_z|+|Im_z|$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Verify that $\sqrt{2}|z| \geq | R_z|+|Im_z|$, suggestion: Reduce this inequality to $(|x|-|y|)^2 \geq0$ (z is a complex number. R stands for real part and Im stands for imaginary part)

Approach: Let $z=x+yi$ where $x,y \in R$. By the triangle property, we have the following $$|x+yi|\geq |x|+|yi|$$

If we multiply the left side by $\sqrt{2}$, the inequality is preserved but who knows if there is equality. That's my problem

Comment: The triangle inequality is the other way around.  $|x+yi|\color{red}{\leq} |x|+|yi|$.  Take for example, $|1+i|=\sqrt{2} \leq 2 = |1|+|i|$

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=a+bi$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Note
$$a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab.$$
This follows immediately from the fact that $(a-b)^2 \geq 0$.  So
$$2(a^2+b^2) \geq a^2+b^2+2ab.$$
Now we take square roots at both sides to get the desired result.

Comment: Can you explain further why the following holds?  $2(a^2+b^2) \geq a^2+b^2+2ab$. I don't have this mathematical sense well developed

Comment: If $a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab$, then we can sum $a^2+b^2$ to both sides to get $a^2+b^2+a^2+b^2=2(a^2+b^2) \geq a^2+b^2+2ab$. When coming up with this, I reasoned backwards, I squared both sides in the inequality that was to be proven and found it was equivalent to the one I use in the proof ($a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab$) which I hapenned to know beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Square both sides to get

$$2|z|^2=2(R_z^2+I_z^2)\ge R_z^2+I_z^2+2|R_z||I_z|$$

Subtracting the right-hand side from the left-hand side gives

$$R_z^2+I_z^2-2|R_z||I_z|=(|R_z|-|I_z|)^2\ge 0$$